# Flutter app closes when left idle overnight but without any crash reports in Google console

Tags: flutter

I have my very first Flutter app for learning vocabulary on Google play store. The app is completely interactive, meaning if the user does not interact with the app, it is completely idle. There are no background processes. I can run the app all day long and it works fine. But when I leave the app running overnight, in the morning, I find that the app has closed. And yet in Google Play Console there are no crashes or ANRs being reported. How do I debug this? I spent a lot of time googling but did not find anything useful.

The same thing happens on iPhone too.

The app was built using Flutter 3.10.5

TIA